# Is it possible to change a matrix keypad to a touch screen with kivy

Tags: pi-4

I have an old test system control board, where the matrix pad went out.

**Control Board**

https://www.ebay.ie/itm/Cincinnati-Test-Systems-PD1277-U3-Control-Board-for-Sentinel-F-21-Flow-Tester-/323639587667

**Matrix Pad**

https://www.ebay.com/itm/390964875134?hash=item5b07528f7e%3Ag%3Ax68AAOSwzOxUWAW%7E&LH_BIN=1

Above show the button layout

** Dirty Layout of Mapping**
[image]

The control board is putting out 5v, so I think that I need to connect to something else there not sure what.
I can make the button layout in kivy. I am not sure how to write the event that triggers the 2 pins to call a button.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: that is a 5 × 4 matrix keypad ... the control panel could be replaced by nine relays and appropriate support circuitry ..... there are many tutorials on the internet about driving relays with a Raspberry Pi

Comment: you could also drill holes in the defective control panel and install pushbutton switches

Comment: Thank you I will see what I can break. Yeah the push button is the last option